# Why is liveuser home directory not present in rootfs.img?

Tags: fedora, rhel, kickstart

If you `unsquash` the `squashfs.img` in a Fedora Live ISO, and then mount the `rootfs.img`, which contains the root file system for the live image, you will see that the `/home` directory is empty.

Yet when you boot from the live image your user is `liveuser` and the directory `/home/liveuser` has "magically" appeared.

Where does this directory come from, if it not there in the `rootfs.img` ?

You can verify in the following way:

```
mount -o loop Fedora.iso /mnt/
mkdir iso
cp -rpf /mnt/* iso/
umount /mnt
unsquashfs iso/LiveOS/squashfs.img
cd squashfs-root/LiveOS
mount -o loop,ro rootfs.img /mnt

ll /mnt/home/
total 0
```

Yet when you boot, you will find a `liveuser` home directory. **How does spontaneously spawn into existence ?**

The weird thing is that in the `fedora-live-base.ks`, this directory and user are actually created:

```
action "Adding live user" useradd \$USERADDARGS -c "Live System User" liveuser
```

Yet there is no `liveuser`.

What is going on here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `liveuser` and its home directory are created during boot by the `livesys` service. The service/init script itself is created in `%post` in the kickstart file -- notice the:

```
cat > /etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys << EOF
```

line in the `%post` script. Everything between lines 64 and 216 in [fedora-live-base.ks](https://pagure.io/fedora-kickstarts/blob/master/f/fedora-live-base.ks) is content of the `livesys` init script so the `useradd` command is not executed during the Live CD creation and the home directory is not created.